# How do I parse xml with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the jQuery alternative to the following JavaScript code?

```
var xmlobject = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlstring, "text/xml");
```

I believe a jQuery alternative would be more cross-browser compatible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124924/can-xml-be-parsed-reliably-using-jquerys-responsexml-syntax and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908899/jquery-wont-parse-xml-with-nodes-called-option (hint: jQuery is not meant to parse xml. It's meant to *traverse* an already parsed DOM tree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cross-browser approach is the following, which I posted a few minutes ago in answer to a similar question:

```
var parseXml;

if (window.DOMParser) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    parseXml = function() { return null; }
}

var xml = parseXml("<foo>Stuff</foo>");
if (xml) {
    window.alert(xml.documentElement.nodeName);
}
```

Comment: Nice. Where jQuery comes in: `$(parseXml("<foo>Stuff</foo>")).find('stuff')` (i.e. this correctly uses jQuery to traverse, not parse).

Answer (score -1):

`var $parsedXml = $(xmlstring);`

For exmaple, if you have something like

```
<object>
  <property id="prop1" value="myVal" />
</object>
```

as your `xmlstring`, you could do

`var prop1 = $(xmlstring).find('#prop1').attr('value');`

to get the value of the object property.

Comment: [This does not work well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908899/jquery-wont-parse-xml-with-nodes-called-option).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at these plugins:

xmlDOM - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/XmlDOM
jParse - http://jparse.kylerush.net/