# Use jQuery .find() on Windows Phone with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I got an issue with Cordova 2.6.0 and jQuery 1.8.1 on Windows Phone !

When I make a `$(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find("Item")` (works on iOS / Android & Browser) it's return an empty element on windows phone... I need to make a `xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.documentElement` and navigate through children to find my element...

So the problem seems jQuery but why ? Any ideas ?

Thanks !

EDIT : The SOAP Envelop I got in return is like this (seen with Fiddler on WP8)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <MethodName xmlns="http://url.com/services/contract">
      <MethodNameResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxx.yyy.aaa.bb.cc.Result" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Item xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxx.yyy.aaa.bb.cc"> 
          <b:Active>Active</b:Active>
          <b:Comment i:nil="true"/>
          <b:Company>My company</b:Company>
          <b:DisplayName>The best company ever</b:DisplayName>
          <b:Email>contact@url.com</b:Email>
          <b:Fax i:nil="true"/>
          <b:FirstName>Alx</b:FirstName>
          <b:GenderTypeId>Male</b:GenderTypeId>
          ...
```

EDIT : `.find("a:Item")` doesn't work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution is to make a new function like this :

```
 $.fn.filterNode = function(name) {
    return this.find('*').filter(function() {
       return this.nodeName === name;
    });
 };
```

And set name to "a:Item" !

I don't know why but this solution works on WindowsPhone Web App !

Answer (score 1):

You should not parse XML that way, but use the ajax method of jQuery and DataType xml.
I don't know if this causes the problem, but it could be.

Check this post:
[Can XML be parsed reliably using jQuery's $(responseXML) syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124924/can-xml-be-parsed-reliably-using-jquerys-responsexml-syntax)

Comment: Indeed my data was "HTTP/1.1" and its return good values and a status "ParseError" but it's work on Chrome / iOS / Android 

Now with XML data type, its return a success status but still no data on Windows Phone

Comment: Thé responsexml never starts with <xml ...> do you know why?