# $.get code not working in IE (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this code, loading XML documents on mouseenter, which works in Firefox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('.invest-port-thumb a').mouseenter(function() {

              $.get(this.href, function(response){

                var cName = $(response).find("fragment cName");
                var cind = $(response).find("fragment cName").attr("cind");

                $('#slider-name .slider-copy').html(cName);
                $('#slider-indu .slider-copy').html(cind);
              });


         });
});
```

and OF COURSE it doesn't work correctly in IE.  In fact, nothing loads.

Sample XML document:

```
<fragment>
    <cName cind="Industrial" stat="Active">ABC Company</cName>  
    <hq>Chicago, IL</hq>
</fragment>
```

I found something strange, when I remove this line:

`var cName = $(response).find("fragment cName");`

it works fine.  For some reason, I can get the attribute of the XML nodes, but not the actual nodes? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Try using $.ajax instead of $.get and changing the dataType to xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you identified:

```
var cName = $(response).find("fragment cName");
```

assigns the jQuery object to the variable `cName`, not it's text content which it looks like you want. Try changing it to

```
var cName = $(response).find("fragment cName").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery should not be used to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908899/jquery-wont-parse-xml-with-nodes-called-option).

Instead, you should specify the `dataType` of the `XmlHttpRequest` to tell the browser to parse the XML, by adding  `, 'xml'` after the callback.
`response` will then be an XML DOM tree, which you can traverse using jQuery.

For example:

```
  $.get(this.href, function(response){

    var cName = $(response).find("fragment cName");
    //...
  }, "xml");
```

Comment: Why not? What happened? What's the value of `response`?