# Dynamic Fields addtions, Submit and Generate XML File

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, web

I would like to generate XML file from HTML Form submission.

The form contains dynamic number of input text fields. For example it may have

> 1-Row-9Cols
>
> 2-Row-4Cols
>
> 3-Row-7Cols

I can add fields on demand.

Is there any framework that I can utilize.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some useful links

[Generate XML document in-memory with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191179/generate-xml-document-in-memory-with-javascript)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/XMLWriter.aspx