# jquery append upper case tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to append uppercase tags into dom object. while try like this, everything converted to lowercase.

```
 $dom = $("<root/>");

 $dom.append("<LName>user10</LName>");

 alert($dom.html()) //<lname>user10</lname>
```

I saw one post in stackoverflow. They suggested to do like this.

```
$dom.append($.parseXML("<LName>user10</LName>").documentElement);
```

This works good in FF, Chrome and safari. But it is not working in IE...

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/WmzHX/)

Comment: Why do you want to insert non-standard HTML tags into your DOM?

Comment: @Lorax maybe his dom isn't html?

Comment: @Lorax to form xml ad send them to webservice.

Comment: It is no working in IE : What have you got ?

Comment: I don't know who downvote my posts. Guys, who down vote this please tell me what is the problem with my post.

Comment: @Aelios <lname>user10</lname>

Comment: why do you use `documentElement`? have you tried `$dom.append($.parseXML("<LName>user10</LName>"));`

Comment: @ftom2 that is not working. see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/WmzHX/)

Comment: Try to use Javascript function : loadXML

Comment: @Aelios i am not loding xml from webservice Or from external xml file. i am trying to form XML myself to give input for webservice.

Comment: could you store the string/xml inside of a hidden `textarea` to keep it from being touched?

Comment: @Eonasdan i think your comment is not relevant to this post.

Comment: mayhaps. why/how are you going to be sending the dom to a web service that requires you to write the dom via javascript?

Comment: If you want to send your own custom-generated XML to a web service, is there anything stopping you from just creating the string manually, without relying on jQuery to build it for you?

Comment: @Eonasdan, @ Lorax Yes, i can code like that. But i collect input for my webservice in various parts of my code. And i manipulate them sometimes. It will be easy to querying if i have my data in dom format.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Generate XML document in-memory with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191179/generate-xml-document-in-memory-with-javascript)

But before you do that, you really have to ask yourself if it's a great idea to generate XML with Javascript.

What I would have done:

- Send the form data to a php file
- php file makes the XML with SimpleXMLElement
- php file send the XML with cURL
- php file returns the data to javascript