# Converting Form Data to XML and submitting it to server

Tags: javascript, xml, webforms

I want to make a simple page that takes form data then converts it to XML and submits it to a webserver. Below is a rough idea of what the form would look like.

```
<form id='form' method='post' action='http://www.THESERVER.com' >
   <p>
   ID: <input type='text' name='ID' />
   </p>
   <p>
   Password: <input type='text' name='password' />
   </p>
     <p>
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
   </p>
</form>
```

Below is an idea of what the XML would need to look like

```
<DATA>
<ID> MY ID</ID>
<password>MY PASSWORD</password>
</Data>
```

I don't have a lot of experience with this but I believe I would need to write some javascript to accomplish this. I did try looking this up but was still unable to find a good starting point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to send XML to the server? What is your backend implementation language and what will the backend do with the XML?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the xml as plain text, this will do: http://jsfiddle.net/f336V/1/

```
var myID = " MY ID" , myPasswd = "MY PASSWORD";
var myXML = "<DATA><ID>"+ escape(myID) +"</ID><password>"+ escape(myPasswd ) +"</password></Data>";
```

---

maybe this helps you more: [Generate XML document in-memory with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191179/generate-xml-document-in-memory-with-javascript)