# stop converting xml tags to lowercase - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am working on Draw.io in which I have to convert json to XML, which I successfully did, But I am facing an issue in which all my xml tags goes to lowercase auto. 
Lets Say, If I create tag with `<mxCell></mxCell>` it will convert into `<mxcell></mxcell>`.
BUT for draw.io , I need to keep the same format for XML. any way to do this ?

```js
var apple = '<mxCell />';
var $div = $('<div>');
$div.append(apple);
$("#graphXMlDiv").text($div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="graphXMlDiv"></div>
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabx4qnq/4/)

Comment: Main problem is, you are using methods intended for HTML manipulation here ... and in HTML, there is no such thing as an element name with upper-case letters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191559/1427878 illustrates a way to go about this.

Comment: Is the text representation or the HTML representation of your XML you want to have ? Is `$("#graphXMlDiv").text('<mxCell></mxCell>');` the result you expected ?

Comment: @Okoch yes this is what i need

Comment: If you only need the text representation don't create node elements with jQuery. Just use text !

Comment: How can I achieve this, Can you share a good example ?

Comment: By using `$div.text(apple);` it gives me `&lt;mxCell /&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this:

```js
let XMLTag = function(tagName) {
  this.tagName = tagName;
  this.children = [];
  this.padding = '';
  this.parent = null;
}

XMLTag.prototype.addPadding = function() {
 this.padding = this.padding + '\t';
}

XMLTag.prototype.getPadding = function() {
 var current = this;
 let padding = '';
 while (current !== null) {
  padding += current.padding;
  current = current.parent;
 }
    return padding;
}

XMLTag.prototype.setParent = function(parent) {
 this.parent = parent;
}

XMLTag.prototype.append = function(child) {
  child.addPadding();
  child.setParent(this);
  this.children.push(child);
}

XMLTag.prototype.toText = function() {
  if (this.children.length === 0) {
    return `${this.getPadding()}<${this.tagName}/>`;
  } else {
    let childrenText = this.children.map(c => c.toText()).join(`\n`);
    return `${this.getPadding()}<${this.tagName}>\n${childrenText}\n${this.getPadding()}</${this.tagName}>` 
  }
}

var apple = new XMLTag('mxCell');
var anotherTag = new XMLTag('anotherTag');
var anotherTag1 = new XMLTag('anotherTag1');
apple.append(anotherTag);
anotherTag.append(anotherTag1);
console.log(apple.toText());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you going for so I am assuming two possible solutions.

**You are looking to insert simple string instead of XML node**

In that case, just do this:

```js
var $div = $('<div/>');
$div.text('<mxCell><mxCell/>');
$("#graphXMlDiv").text($div.text());
//Then I would add the answer to this StackOverflow question
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="graphXMlDiv"></div>
```

Notice I don't use `$div.html()` to supply the data to `$('#graph....')` because what you've inserted inside `$div` is not proper HTML, and should not be treated as such.

**In case you wanted to load an XML document and then add into $div the content of what the XML node myCell has, then you can do something like this.**

```js
var apple = '<mxCell>Data inside mxCell</mxCell>',
  $div = $('<div/>')
$apple_xml = $($.parseXML(apple));
$apple_xml.find('mxCell').each(function() {
  $div.html($(this).text());
});
$("#graphXMlDiv").text($div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="graphXMlDiv"></div>
```