# regular expression repeating subexpression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text

```
<pattern name="pattern1"/>
<success>success case 1</success>
<failed> failure 1</failed>
<failed> failure 2</failed>
<unknown> unknown </unknown>
<pattern name="pattern4"/>
<pattern name="pattern5"/>        
<success>success case 3</success> 
<pattern name="pattern2"/>        
<success>success case 2</success>
<otherTag>There are many other tags.</otherTag>
<failed> failure 3</failed>
<pattern name="pattern3"/> 
<unknown>unkown</unknown>
```

And the regular expression `<failed>[\w|\W]*?</failed>` matches all the lines contains failed tag.

What do I need to to if I want all failed tags and the pattern tag above the failed tag. if there is no failed tag underneath a pattern tag, then the pattern tag should not be matched?
Basically, I want the following output:

```
<pattern name="pattern1"/>
<failed> failure 1</failed>
<failed> failure 2</failed>
<pattern name="pattern2"/>
<failed> failure 3</failed>
```

I am doing this in javascript, I do not mind of doing some intermediate steps.

***edit start***
Almost all repliers suggest me to take a different approach. I am unsure which approach I should take. JQuery, regex or others. I am giving more information here for better decision making.
The data format would change, but would not change often. The data is from a schematron validition report of file type ".SVRL" The structure of the file are have the following schema defined using "[RELAX NG compact syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG)"

```
schematron-output   = element schematron-output {
attribute title { text }?,
attribute phase { xsd:NMTOKEN }?,
attribute schemaVersion { text }?,
    human-text*,
    ns-prefix-in-attribute-values*,
    (active-pattern,
    (fired-rule, (failed-assert | successful-report)*)+)+
}
```

the  maps to active-pattern,  and  matches to failed-assert and successful-report respectively.

Now with additional information, which approach should I be taking?
Thanks very much for helping out. :)

***edit end***

Comment: See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and [XML parsing in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript).  Most JavaScript environments have good support for XML parsing.  You don't want to use regex.

Comment: On a side note, `|` doesn't mean "or" in a character class, it just matches `|`.  "Or" is implicit in character classes anyway; `[\w\W]` means "a word character or a non-word character."

Comment: @Matthew:thanks a lot for your suggestion, I would evaluate your option.
@Alan: Thanks so much for pointing  out the "|" doesn't mean "or" in character class. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the RegExp you need:

```
<(pattern|failed)\b[^>]*(?:/>|>[^<]*</\1>)
```

Just escape the slashes when using in Javascript regular expression notation:

```
var regExp = /<(pattern|failed)\b[^>]*(?:\/>|>[^<]*<\/\1>)/gi;
var matchesArray = testString.match(regExp);
```

This regular expression will find whole <pattern> and <failed> tags, either if they are empty tags or not (<empty/> or <notEmpty></notEmpty>). It also considers possible element attributes.

Comment: Hi smnh, sorry I slightly edited my question, your regular expression worked perfectly well for my original requirement, any chance you can have a at the new text to be parsed?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into methods other than regular expressions to parse XML, particularly if:

- your requirements are likely to change in future, making your regular expression increasingly unweildy
- you are parsing data from a third-party source, which may contain just about anything, including strings that look like XML tags embedded in XML comments, CDATA sections or attributes.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript) for information about XML parsing in Javascript.

The easy solution is "use jQuery".  If for some reason you don't want to load jQuery to do this, then [start here](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_parser.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex "|" operator (meaning "or") to create a regex that will match one or more expressions.  For example ...

```
/^<failed>[\w|\W]*?<\/failed>|^<pattern[^>]*>/
```

... should do what you're asking (based on the example you've given above).

But, as other commenters have said, parsing XML with regexs is a slippery slope. You'll probably want to look into other options, like using the DocumentFragment class to parse your string for you.

Comment: Thanks broofa, your answer does exactly as I wanted.  I understand others' concern, but the file structure is unlikely to change in the future (I added more comments). I am inclined to use regex.

Comment: Hi broofa, sorry I slightly edited my question, your regular expression worked perfectly well for my original requirement, any chance you can have a at the new text to be parsed?