# Escape quotes inside certain html elements with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tend to use the [image solution described by 24Ways](http://24ways.org/2005/have-your-dom-and-script-it-too) to use ajax and scripts.

However, The ajax results are out of my control and I need a regexp to escape the quotes (' and ") since the scripts will house in an onload attribute.

This is my work so far:

```
clean_txt = clean_txt.replace(
    /<script[^>]*>([\n\s\S]+?)<\/script>/img, 
    "<img src='1px.gif?d=$1' alt='' onload='new Function(\"$1\")();' />"
);
```

Does anyone have the final regexp, e g to escape the quotes in $1?

Comment: The `<center>` cannot hold! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: lol, totally missed that one. bookmarked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it could be solved by escaping the wrapper quotes on the onload function.

```
clean_txt = clean_txt.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\n\s\S]+?)<\/script>/img, 
            "<img src='1px.gif?d=$1' alt='' onload=\'$1\;\' />");
```

A bit ugly and weird, but I can live with that. By doing this, browsers seems to walk around the problem theirselves.

I have tested in Opera 10.6, Firefox 3.6, Safari 5 and Chrome 7.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing html with regex will destroy your soul.

I'd really suggest using something simpler like:

```
clean_txt.replace("'","\\'").replace('"', '\\"');
```

Of course, this will replace every `'` with `\'` and `"` with `\"`. If you don't want that, read more about [XML parsing in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript).

Comment: Unfortunately, the results I'm getting are not reliable enough to be evaluated as XML. But thanks anyway.

Comment: This will not replace every quote.  It will only replace the first of each quote type.  `'aaa'.replace('a', 'b') === 'baa'`.  You need to use regexp replace : `'aaa'.replace(/a/g, 'b') === 'bbb'`, and probably replace them with HTML entities instead of back-slash escape.