# JsonP call to other server with XML output?

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript, JSONP and reading XML from cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578890/javascript-jsonp-and-reading-xml-from-cross-domain)

I know that JSONP can get a JSON data from other server which produce this JSON data (wrapped with callback...).

But lets say i want to get xml data from other server's response. (via jQuery Ajax)

Is it possible ? or the other server must produce this XML data also via JSON ?