# pulling XML data from external site

Tags: html, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to pull data from an XML file that isn't hosted on my own site. I'm completely new to this so I have no idea where I'm going wrong. I can pull that data from my own site easy. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  url = "http://elcu.herobo.com/testarea/include/cd_catalog.xml"
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

  document.write("<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width'90%' id='1' class='tablesorter'><thead><tr> <th>Artist</th> <th>Title</th> <th>Country</th></thead><tbody>");

  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
      document.write("<tr><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
  document.write("</tbody></table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you are, by default, not allowed to do cross-domain requests to get XML data ([same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). If you want to get data across domains, you usually need to use JSON-P as your format, or setup a proxy within your own domain that you can access the data through.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd never write this, but, "You might consider using jQuery for this." It provides all the sauce for the different browsers and also support for JSON-P that you'll need for CORS, unless you can get the server to start returning CORS headers to permit your access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to page, that isn't hosted on your server (I suppose you don't), you can use JSONP (for more details, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5593104/617996)), otherwise you should use PROXY (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579158/617996)).