# how to Fetch data from an XML file with tags <title> <![CADTA[text here]]> </title>?

Tags: javascript, xml, cdata

My XMl File

> <item>
>
> <title>
>   <![CDATA[Stanford engineers build a nanoscale device for brain-inspired computing]]>
>
> </title>
>
> <link>
>
> http://news.stanford.edu/news/2011/july/nano-synapse-computing-061211.html
>   </link>
>
> </item>

I am able to fetch easily from link by using the tag

`alert(obj.item.link)`

Now i want to fetch from the title tag ie."Stanford engineers build...."
i have tried everything 
ie

```
alert(obj.item.title)

alert(obj.item.title.CDATA);
```

but none is working , any help

Comment: Why is this tagged json? Why is this tagged cross-domain? How are you converting the XML into a JavaScript object?

Comment: well i am fetching the xml feed via json and den converting into html via javascript thats why

Comment: You can't fetch an XML feed via JSON. They are both data formats. You might have a third party service that converts XML into JSON which you then fetch, in which case the XML (which you are sharing with us) is irrelevant and the JSON (which you aren't) isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good explanation of how to do this here: http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2007/04/accessing-cdata-section-in-xml-dom-from.html.

However, I'd suggest a jQuery-based solution to hide any browser differences.  See this SO question: [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript).