# conversion of xml recordset to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to convert xml recordset loaded using javascript into javascript array...

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 function load() {
var xmlDso=myXML.XMLDocument;
xmlDso.load("myxxml.xml");
var memberset=myXML.recordset;

 }
 </script>
```

In the above if i want to convert memberset into javascript array to use further how to do?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>XML DSO-example3.htm</title>
 <script language="JavaScript">
  function load() {
var xmlDso=myXML.XMLDocument;
xmlDso.load("myxxml.xml");
var memberset=myXML.recordset;
                                  here i need to change recordset to array
 }
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onLoad="load()">

<object id="myXML" CLASSID="clsid:550dda30-0541-11d2-9ca9-0060b0ec3d39" width="0" 

height="0"></object>

<table datasrc="#myXML" border="1">
<thead> 
<th>id</th>   
<th>name</th>  
<th>collagename</th>
<th>committedAmount</th> 
<th>defaulted</th>  
<th>total</th>  
</thead> 
<tr>    
<td><div datafld="id"></div></td>  
<td><div datafld="name"></div></td>  
<td><div datafld="collagename"></div></td>  
<td><div datafld="committedAmount"></div></td>  
<td><div datafld="defaulted"></div></td>  
<td><div datafld="total"></div></td>  
</tr>  
</table>  

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: what is myXML in the code above?

Comment: Can you display that part too?

Comment: Check this URL may be useful for you http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/XMLtoJavaScript.htm

Comment: I don't find a method to access the record fields from javascript. So I don't think it is possible with xmlDSO. Instead u can use Microsoft.XMLDOM activex

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer, how to parse XML in JavaScript:

[XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript)

But, I would reconsider design. Instead of request/return data in XML, much more convenient to use JSON.