# How to get soap address location attribute from wsdl document in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

How can I get or retrieve the address location from this tag in JavaScript and Java?

```
<soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx"/>
```

I am using this WSDL: http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl

Comment: See maybe this question: [XML parsing in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript)