# How to store, retrieve and process XML contents in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, match

I would like to perform a regex match on some XML content in JavaScript.

1. How do we store XML contents in a JavaScript variable?
2. What are the effective ways to retrieve the XML content from a JavaScript variable to perform a regex match?
3. Note: Please suggest code snippets that works in all the browsers.

Sangeeth

Comment: XML is just a string ? or some other object ? can you include some examples

Comment: Yes, we can consider the XML content as a string which includes characters like <, >, ", % ., /, \, etc. For example, consider the following XML content should be stored in a javascript variable to perform some regex operations.    <table>
<tr><td class="webkit-line-number"></td><td class="webkit-line-content"><span class="webkit-html-tag">&lt;/table&gt;</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class="webkit-line-number"></td><td class="webkit-line-content"></td></tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is generally a bad idea for parsing XML.

Here is a solution using jQuery : [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Finally, I used document.body.innerHTML, document.getElementsByTagName(), etc functions to parse the html/xml content.

Answer (score 0):

> How do we store XML contents in a JavaScript variable?

That depends on where you are getting the XML from. If you get fetching it over HTTP, then XMLHttpRequest will create an XML object for you (in `obj.responseXML`). If you are embedded the markup in a string then I believe [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser) is fairly well supported (and pairs with MSXML.DOMDocument in Microsoft-land)

> What are the effective ways to retrieve the XML content from a JavaScript variable

DOM and XPath

> to perform a regex match?

I hope you mean "to perform a regex match on text extracted from the XML". Regular expressions are a very poor tool for parsing XML.