# Retrieving All the values of an XML document in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

I have this XML document

```
<xml>
 <word>
   <threeletter>rip</threeletter>
   <fourletter>Pier</fourletter> 
   <fiveletter>Spire</fiveletter>
   <sixletter>Spider</sixletter>
 </word>
 <word>
   <threeletter>rip</threeletter>
   <fourletter>Pier</fourletter> 
   <fiveletter>Spire</fiveletter>
   <sixletter>Spider</sixletter>
 </word>
 <word>
   <threeletter>rip</threeletter>
   <fourletter>Pier</fourletter> 
   <fiveletter>Spire</fiveletter>
   <sixletter>Spider</sixletter>
 </word>
</xml>
```

Let's assume that each element inside the word has different values.
is it possible in javascript to retrieve all of these values? then store them in an array? or a variable? if so how? because I am planning to compare them with user inputs

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all clear how you want your array structured.

Here is one example that store multiple arrays in an object

```
var words={ threeletter:[], fourletter:[], fiveletter:[], sixletter:[]};
var xmlItems=['threeletter','fourletter', 'fiveletter', 'sixletter'];

$(xml).find('word').each(function(){
    var $word=$(this);
    $.each( xmlItems, function(i, item){
        words[item].push( $word.find( item ).text());
    });    
});
```

To access  3 letter array  use `words.threeletter`

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/5EnR2/

Comment: it's not working/running of jsfiddle, I click run there's nothing happening

Comment: it is logging to console the `words` object. Look in browser console. Will break in IE unless you have installed console in IE. IE is a poor developer browser to use for js

Comment: how do I do it if I have an external XML?  and is that Jquery?

Comment: load the xml with ajax and run code above in success callback

Comment: use google... look for "jquery ajax xml", should find tons of results

Comment: but is this possible using javascript only?

Comment: yes is possible...use jQuery ajax to load the xml from external file

Comment: I can't find a link to any site that does that

Comment: I forgot about selecting this as a best answer. but it did help, what I did was created my own construction of way which basically stores all words. but thanks for giving for an idea. on a side note I also Tested this and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Two ways :):

- jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/
- not jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_examples.asp (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_parsertest)

Comment: but what if I have to get all of those value? and store them into a local variable?