# How can I add multiple markers on a Google Map from XML coordinate data?

Tags: google-maps, xml-parsing, google-maps-markers

I have this data in XML format:

```
<DOCUMENT>
    <IDS>53850_WP</IDS>
    <FULL_NAME>Maybank</FULL_NAME>
    <AD_WEIGHT>60</AD_WEIGHT>
    <MAP>200:37.3321363,-122.0278287</MAP>
    <PHONE>00-2222 3466</PHONE>
    <CLASS_DESC>Banks</CLASS_DESC>
</DOCUMENT>

<DOCUMENT>
    <IDS>53850_WP</IDS>
    <FULL_NAME>Maybank</FULL_NAME>
    <AD_WEIGHT>60</AD_WEIGHT>
    <MAP>200:37.3321363,-122.0278287</MAP>
    <PHONE>00-2222 3466</PHONE>
    <CLASS_DESC>Banks</CLASS_DESC>
</DOCUMENT>

<DOCUMENT>
    <IDS>53850_WP</IDS>
    <FULL_NAME>Maybank</FULL_NAME>
    <AD_WEIGHT>60</AD_WEIGHT>
    <MAP>200:37.3321363,-122.0278287</MAP>
    <PHONE>00-2222 3466</PHONE>
    <CLASS_DESC>Banks</CLASS_DESC>
</DOCUMENT>
```

How do I split the `<MAP>` value to lat and long? The `<MAP>` node is a coordinate. And, how to mark those locations in Google Maps? I'm using JSP. I don't know how to add multiple markers to the map.

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about parsing XML in JavaScript, you can look at this answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412989/1314132.

To learn more about placing a `google.maps.Marker`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) on the map, take a look at the [**Markers** section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers).