# Get City name from GPS co-ordinates

Tags: gps, google-api, city

I want to get the name of the city from the GPS coordinates.
I can get the details of the GPS points using Google API

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters
```

Where output is XML which I don't want to be...
For example

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xmllatlng=53.244921,-2.479539&sensor=false&region=gb
```

returns me the XML details of the coordinates.... Which I don't think is easy to get the name of the City....
I want only the name of the city..
Thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct URL is below

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=53.244921,-2.479539&sensor=true
```

In anycase, the xml is perfectly fine to get a city. In this case

```
<address_component>
    <long_name>Northwich</long_name>
    <short_name>Northwich</short_name>
    <type>postal_town</type>
</address_component>
```

is what you are looking for. 
Not sure what language you are wishing to get this information from in though.
From the looks of your other questions you work with javascript.
So i suggest learning how to XML parse with javascript.

SO has a great post on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: It looks like Google won't make it easy to find the city from this data,  however if you are working with JavaScript you will probably want to use JSON. So try this instead.  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.244921,-2.479539&sensor=true

Comment: There are cases in which the "postal_town" doesn't exist. see http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%EC%84%BC%ED%94%84%EB%9E%80%EC%8B%9C%EC%8A%A4%EC%BD%94&sensor=true&language=en