# Android: How can i find user's city via gps?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, city, geocoder

I develop a new application in android studio. I want to find user's city. I tried with Geocoder but some times it returns null. Is there any way that i can find user's city? I already know his latitude and longitude

Comment: Are you in an online state?  If so - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913870/get-city-name-from-gps-co-ordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the lat and long, you can do this.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding

You will use this API like so... you would have have to parse out the JSON
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=LAT,LONG&key=ENTER_API_KEY

Comment: I have already found this api BUT it returns me a large json file with huge information in "results" array. I just want the city name and this will be a very time consuming solution i thing..

Comment: "i think". do you expect there to be a soution that says, 23424,423424 = new york new york? the time to call this or ANY api would be similar. the time to parse an array would be more time consuming. but I bet you would have a response back within a second

Comment: yes but user will download the entire file every time only to find just a name. Thank you for your respond! I am just looking for a better solution for my problem if it exists (not only an api).

Comment: My app works only with user's city... So user should download the api every time that he opens the app with his gps.

Comment: Thanks. Good luck, happy coding. How about a thumbs up? :)

Comment: i can't because i have low reputation :P. It will help me your thumbs up though. :)

Comment: Ok now i have reputation hehe!