# How to implement a SOAP call using XDomainRequest in IE8

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, cross-domain, xdomainrequest

I'm trying to call a WCF service using soap in IE8 and I can't seem to get my head around how xdr's work. Can they be used to pass xml to a soap endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can they be used to pass xml to a soap endpoint?

We are basically talking about a POST request with a properly formatted XML SOAP payload and you can sure do that with the [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. Here is a basic example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xdr;

    function soapTest() {
        var data =  '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">' +
                    '   <soapenv:Body>' +
                    '      <tem:Add>' +
                    '         <tem:a>1</tem:a>' +
                    '         <tem:b>2</tem:b>' +
                    '      </tem:Add>' + 
                    '   </soapenv:Body>' +
                    '</soapenv:Envelope>';

        if (window.XDomainRequest) {
            xdr = new XDomainRequest();
            if (xdr) {
                xdr.onerror = function() { alert("an error occured"); };
                xdr.ontimeout = function() { alert("timeout"); };
                xdr.onload = function() { alert(xdr.responseText); }
                xdr.timeout = 10000;
                xdr.open("post", "http://SomeServer/SoapCalculator");
                xdr.send(data);
            } else {
                alert("Failed to create XDR");
            }
        } else {
            alert("XDR doesn't exist");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The payload in the example is [for a web service exposing this contract](http://www.html2xml.nl/Services/Calculator/Version1/Calculator.asmx?wsdl). You could create a mock web service based on that WSDL on a server that responds with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Then, if all goes well you should see a response like this:

[image]

You can then [parse the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript) to extract the data you need instead of printing the raw string.

For troubleshooting also have a look at the following post: [XDomainRequest - Restrictions, Limitations and Workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).

Comment: Bogdan, my man! Not only does that rhyme but it conveys that you answered the question well. Thanks. One other thing to consider is that for an XDR there is a preflight OPTIONS request that checks for the access-control-allow-origin value and the allowed options. Tricky in WCF.