# What is the XML equivalent of JSON.parse in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

As part of a server-client project I have an object in a C#-server app which is serialized to an XML string.
The string looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CandyShop xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CandyList>
   <CandyDesc>
     <Taste>Taste1</Taste>
     <Color>Color1</Color>
   </CandyDesc>
   <CandyDesc>
     <Taste>Taste2</Taste>
     <Color>Color2</Color>
   </CandyDesc>
  </CandyList>
  <!-- Other stuff -->
</CandyShop>
```

I then transfer this XML string via websockets to a javascript-based HTML client.
I'd like to deserialize the initial class so that I could just type

```
var aColor = CandyShop.CandyList.CandyDesc[0].Color;
```

For JSON strings I just use

```
JSON.parse(stringToParse);
```

Is there an equivalent for XML?

Bonus if I can pre-create a CandyShop class and map the fields directly.

Comment: please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript

Comment: @HuiZheng: Is there an echo in here? ;-)

Comment: I already saw the other question, but I was rather looking for something which didn't return a DOM tree.

Comment: jsonml (http://www.jsonml.org/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to JSON.parse for dealing with XML, this is because what XML does is not directly equivalent to what JSON does so reading it in this way doesn't make sense in general. Read the link T. J. Crowder provides in the comment above for details on how to carry out XML parsing.