# JavaScript XML handling

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML and XML knowledge and completely new to Javascript.

I have a table in a html. Now I need to update some fields in the table with a XML file. E.g. update the total field in the table with the sales field in the XML file. The total should = total + sales.

Comment: thotwielder, Stack Overflow follows a Q&A format and you don't really have a question here. What, _precisely_, are you asking? What have you tried so far, if anything? Where is the XML coming from/how are you getting it?

Comment: Please refer to the following question that already asked.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript>

Comment: @Dinooppaloli: No, that's the wrong direction to look for. The buzzwords to search for are AJAX and DOM manipulation.

Comment: @dgvid: as I said I am completely new to JavaScript. So my question is very general like where should I begin. I don't even know it's doable or not. If I knew a precise question to ask normally that would not be a question. The XML is from local. Let's say it's just a experimental project. I know how to do it using like Java + web server etc. But I am targeted to see if it's doable using Javascript . Thanks.

Comment: @Dinooppaloli: the JQuery looks like something that will work. I am going to try out. Thanks.