# Get content between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to extract the content of a tag, here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAU0AAAD6CAYAAAAlSBW9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhehP1lnB3H1a4P75Ely8zMzOyYHcccjsNOHNtx7IDtJCbJgtEwM4tG0kgzghnRaEgMI2aWLNlisMVMlgxa73Wv2tvJ85xz ...
</string>
```

And here is what I want:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAU0AAAD6CAYAAAAlSBW9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhehP1lnB3H1a4P75Ely8zMzOyYHcccjsNOHNtx7IDtJCbJgtEwM4tG0kgzghnRaEgMI2aWLNlisMVMlgxa73Wv2tvJ85xz ...
```

I tried with this regexp:

```
iframeContents.match(/<string[^>]*>(.*?)<\/string>/i);
```

but I keep getting the string tag and no more the xml one:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAU0AAAD6CAYAAAAlSBW9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhehP1lnB...
```

Comment: Feels like it's time to link to the most famous answer on SO, again -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If this is in browser why not get the browser to do it for [you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript). If its nodejs use a [libary](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Element)

Comment: Thanks for replies. I use mootools and I don't know how the equivalent of .find. I see nothing like that in the doc

Comment: The answer with the most upvotes shows how to do it in pure js. you can then use normal DOM munipulation tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
iframeContents.match( /<string[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/string>/i )[1]
```

Match returns an array, or `null` if there is no match.
The first element of the array is the whole match, the second element is the text matched by the first capture group `()`.

`.` doesn't match newlines, but `[\s\S]` does.

Answer (score 0):

using the parse xml method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript/8412989#8412989)

```
var parseXml;

if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" &&
       new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    throw new Error("No XML parser found");
})

var xml = parseXml("...");
var text = xml.documentElement.firstChild.nodeValue;
```