# Cross Domain AJAX GET Call fails to get the XML response

Tags: xml, ajax

I have a Web service URL on request it will return an XML response. When i directly post the URL in the browser i am getting the response. But when i do an AJAX call it fails.

Chrome Error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Firefox Error: XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{e0bbb28b-e8ae-4b43-a266-428a24f9278d} Line Number 1, Column 1.

All the params like username,password query string are passed in the webservice URL.

Apologies: I cannot post the code and the URL.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can't post anything, you'd better go to some search engine with " Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  and maybe end-up to some interesting content like http://stackoverflow.com/a/8456586/1236044

Comment: If you want help, you're going to have to post the code.

Comment: Check out this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618401/how-to-load-an-external-xml-from-javascript/18193257#answer-18193257

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run AJAX to a different domain (also known as cross-domain AJAX).
This works when you're running directly from the browser because there's no cross domain restriction when doing that.

Solutions:
- Use CORS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
- Use JSONP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
- USe proxy on the server side

Related questions:
- [CORS - Cross-Domain AJAX Without JSONP By Allowing Origin On Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318426/cors-cross-domain-ajax-without-jsonp-by-allowing-origin-on-server)

Answer (score 0):

**Fix for client side code:**

If you are sending a `$.get` request, you need to pass Data-Type as 'jsonp' for cross domain AJAX get.

You may also try $.getJSON method.
You can read more in *[The jQuery Cross-Domain Ajax Guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide)*.

**OR**

**Fix for server side code:**

You may enable cross domain serving, eg. in PHP

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```