# Parse xml with javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to parse xml output with javascript without jquery.

What is the best and practice about this problems?

Comment: Where are you getting your output from? Why don't you want to use jQuery? What does your XML look like? Do you have a specific example of the problem you are facing?

Comment: What have you searched / tried / failed at / need help with?

Comment: MDN has a great article on XPath: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: Here is an answer for another question about parsing xml with javascript http://stackoverflow.com/a/8412989/1804496

Answer (score 5):

you can use the DOMParser ( or ActiveX if is Internet Explorer ) like below...

```
if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
    tmp = new DOMParser();
    xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
} else { // IE
    xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
    xml.async = "false";
    xml.loadXML( data );
}

//the XML is a xml document now :D
```

to navigate you can use

```
xml.getElementsByTagName("tagName");
xml.querySelector("selector");
xml.querySelectorAll("[attr=value]");
//and others
```