# Loading and reading XML files in cocos2d-x 3.0 javascript scripts

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, cocos2d-x, spidermonkey, cocos2d-x-3.0

How should one proceed to load XML content from a javascript script in cocos2d-x 3.0?

I need to parse an XML file but `DOMParser` is unavailable:

```
var text="<note>";
text=text+"<content>whatever blablabla</content>";
text=text+"</note>";

var parser=new DOMParser();
var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
```

results in **`ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined`**.

How should I proceed to load and manipulate the XML?

---

Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649783/171711) solution fails:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument("");
```

**`ReferenceError: document is not defined`**.

From the [V2.2.1 documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V2.2.1/index.html) I tried the SAXParser to no avail:

```
cc.SAXParser.getInstance().parse(fullPath);
```

**`TypeError: cc.SAXParser is undefined`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paliate to the removal of `cc.SAXParser` in cocos2d-x 3.0 the solution is to use a [pure javascript parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056881/171711) until a better solution is made available.