# Load an xml file with javascript in XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, extract

I am stuck at this. I have an XSLT file that uses an XML file to retrieve data from it.
IN this XSLT file is also a javascript. It's purpose is to create counters to the 'for each' statement in the XSLT.

Now I need to add a feature to the javascript that gets a specific entry from the XML file.
I will paste a part of the xml here so I can explain further.

```
<ROW>
    <Date>03-12-2013</Date>
    <School>SvR</School>
    <Locale>B1.04</Locale>
    <Class>1236VUGK16</Class>
    <Time>09:00-16:00</Time>
</ROW>
```

I need to get the data from "Date". But I do not know how to load an xml file in javascript to achieve this. I've found some html codes that tell me to `xmlDoc.load` will do this, but it does not. It will give me a syntax error. Is this because it is in XSLT? How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: For parsing XML in Javascript, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/649614/15996

Answer (score 1):

you need 4 things

1. data.xml -> XML file
2. Openxml.js -> contains funciton to open Javascript
3. filejs.js -> contains function to read/write and others things with data.
4. index.html -> show information

part 1, your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
<ROW>
<Date>03-12-2013</Date>
    <School>SvR</School>
    <Locale>B1.04</Locale>
    <Class>1236VUGK16</Class>
    <Time>09:00-16:00</Time>
</ROW>
</events>
```

part 2:

```
unction OpenFile(fichXML)
{
        var xmlDoc=undefined;
        try
        {
            if (document.all) //IE
            {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            }
            else //firefox
            {
                xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
            }
            xmlDoc.async=false;
            xmlDoc.load(fichXML);


        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try { //otros safari, chrome
                    var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("GET",fichXML,false);
                    xmlhttp.send(null);
                    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
                    return xmlDoc;
            } 
            catch (e) 
            {
                return undefined;
            }

        }
        return xmlDoc;
}
```

part 3:

```
    function Event(date)
    {
        this.date = date;

    }   
    //funciton to charge XMLElements
     function ChargeXMLElements()
        {
            try
            {
                xmlDoc=OpenFile("data.xml");
                eventosXML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ROW');

                if (eventosXML.length>0)
                {
                    eventos=new Array(); //clase con los datos cargados
                 }
                for(var i=0; i< eventosXML.length; i++) 
                {
                    xmlEvento=eventosXML[i];

                    fecha=xmlEvento.getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                    evento = new Evento(fecha);       
                    eventos.push(evento);

                }
                return eventos;
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert("Error on the load data");
            }    

        }
//show information take on previously function, and show on a table (with only 1 column)
function showinformation() 
{
        var tr;
        var td;
        var tabla;
        var l=0;
        ev= CargarXMLEventos();
        auxUnEven=ev.pop();
        tabla=document.getElementById("datos");
        while (auxUnEven!=undefined)
        {
            tr=tabla.insertRow(l);
            //creamos las columnas de la tabla 
            td=tr.insertCell(0);
            td.innerHTML=auxUnEven.date;
            /*td=tr.insertCell(1);
            td.innerHTML=auxUnEven.hora;
            td=tr.insertCell(2);
            td.innerHTML=auxUnEven.comentario;   */ //if you need more columns         
            l++;
            auxUnEven=ev.pop();
        }
        if (l==0)
        {
            tabla=document.getElementById("datos");
            tr=tabla.insertRow(l);
            td=tr.insertCell(0);
            td.innerHTML=" dont have events ";
        }

}
```

part 4:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>example XML</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="filejs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Openxml.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <table id="datos">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            showinformation();
        </script>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

i think that is functional but i don't know. I see the information here: http://elcaminillo.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/leer-xml-en-javascript/ (spanish, sorry)