# how to hide some specified nodes from XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

**how to hide some specified nodes from XML data**
for example my XML data is like this

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>
   <primary>hyd</primary>
   <secondary>delhi</secondary>
</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**i want to hide from tag and child nodes while i am displaying this data in a page using java script or jquery.**

Comment: Hide it from what? Ze germans?

Comment: i don't want to display <from></from> tag and its child elements.

Answer (score 2):

Well try to parse it, once you've loaded it up into an object, you can manipulate it however you like.

How to parse it, can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript/8412989#8412989)

Try if something like this works (using jQuery 1.5 or newer):

```
var xml = '<note> <to>Tove</to> <from> <primary>hyd</primary> <secondary>delhi</secondary> </from> <heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Dont forget me this weekend! </body></note > ';

var parsedXml = $.parseXML(xml);

$(parsedXml).find('form').remove();
```