# How to read XML server response in JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, xml

I work on a web project and at this point I need to pass a hard-coded xml from Java to JavaScript to parse that xml; the problem is that I don't know exactly how to do this. As shown below, my xml is stored in a String variable, so I need to pass this variable to JavaScript. 
I'm using tomcat as a server.

Java Code - that creates xml:

```
@Path("/getXml")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getXml(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException{

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("news-counts");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        int j=12;
        for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
            Element item = document.createElement("item");
            rootElement.appendChild(item);
            item.setAttribute("count", "" + j);
            item.setAttribute("date", "201408" + "0" + i);
            j=j+2;
        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        // transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
        String xmlOutput = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");

       // return Response.status(Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).entity("xmlOutput").build();        
       //System.out.println(xmlOutput);

        return xmlOutput;        

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Searcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        return null;
    }

}
```

JavaScript code - how I tried to acces the xmlOutput variable

```
function test() {

var r=new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication6/tavi/searcher/getXml" , false);

r.send(); 
var responseText = r.responseText;
alert(responseText);
}
```

Comment: The "easy" way would be to switch to JSON.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest`s include a [`responseXML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties) for XML responses. Provided a valid response, it should hold a DOM document created from the XML.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse your xml in javascript by this way -

```
  var content = xml_string;//your xml string variable                       

    if (typeof content == 'string') {
    content = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(content, "text/xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use [Jquery](http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery) for parsing xml. Heres another one [Easy XML Consumption using jQuery](http://www.compoc.com/tuts/). If you prefer pure javascript look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript).

**Using Jquery:**

```
    var xml = $.parseXML("<news-counts><item count=\"1\" date=\"2014-08-13 00:00:00\">Stuff</item><item count=\"2\" date=\"2014-08-13 01:01:01\">Bar</item></news-counts>");
    var x = xml.getElementsByTagName('item');
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
        console.log(x.item(i).textContent); //Stuff Bar
        console.log(x.item(i).getAttribute('count')); //1 2
        console.log(x.item(i).getAttribute('date')); //2014-08-13 00:00:00  2014-08-13 01:01:01  
        }
```

**Using javascript:**

```
var parseXml;
    if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
        parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
            return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
        };
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" &&
           new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
        parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
            var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
            return xmlDoc;
        };
    } else {
        throw new Error("No XML parser found");
    }
    var xml = parseXml("<news-counts><item count=\"1\" date='2014-08-13 00:00:00'>Stuff</item><item count=\"2\" date='2014-08-13 00:00:00'>Bar</item></news-counts>");//get attributes or contents after this line
```

Comment: Thank you. I found where "getXml" snapped. I removed the "try-catch" statement and now I can acces my string; it's very odd.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse xml by jQuery. Ref: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html