# Java: Get value of XML String/Response?

Tags: java, xml

I am having this XML response from Flickr API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<user id="myID">
    <username>myUserName</username>
</user>
</rsp>
```

I never used XML in Java before, how can I extract the following field data:
"rsp stat" should return ok 
"username" should return myUserName

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go ahead and make your own parser, using regex or the sort. That would be a long way to do it.

A faster and more conveinient way of doing it would be using a library such as [this one](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/).