# XML into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, xml-parsing

Can somebody tell me how to parse information from XML to array.
So I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<name>
  <gps>coordinate1</gps>
  <gps>coordinate2</gps>
  ...
</name>
...
```

So I would like to pull out the value of the name tag, put it into a variable, and then pull out the value of the gps tag, basically the coordinates and store them into an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @LJ: That might be part of the answer, but I see most of the question as being how to extract the data from the document once you have it in DOM form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
            parser.async="false";
            var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString ("<name><gps>a</gps><gps>b</gps></name>", "text/xml");
            var nameNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];
            var result = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i< nameNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var gpsNode = nameNode.childNodes[i];
                result.push(gpsNode.innerHTML);
            } 

            console.log(result);
```

Comment: When I try the following ajax call:  var response = '';  
$.ajax({ type: "GET",      url: "test.php",      async: false,      success : function(text)      {      response = text;      }  });
I can not parse with the code that you provided.