# How to get Child nodes of XML parent tag based on attribute

Tags: javascript, xml

I have been trying to display all child nodes of the parent node based on the attribute type using JS

**Requirement:**

user gives three  I/P as :

1)"Ram" "Student" "a1"

O/P :should display all the child elements based on name & type selected

**aaa,aaaaaaaa,aaaa**

2)"Ram" "Student" "a2" :

**xxxx,tttttt,yyyy**

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <program name="Ram">
        <computation type="student">
            <module type="a1">              
                <modPath>aaa</modPath>
                <modInputTemplate>aaaaaaaa</modInputTemplate>
                <modSchematic>aaaa</modSchematic>
            </module>
            <module type="a2">              
                <modPath>xxxx</modPath>
                <modInputTemplate>tttttt</modInputTemplate>
                <modSchematic>yyyy</modSchematic>
            </module>
        </computation>
        <computation type="Employee">
            <module type="b1">              
                <modPath>lllll</modPath>
                <modInputTemplate>llllll</modInputTemplate>
                <modSchematic>lllll</modSchematic>
            </module>
            <module type="b2">              
                <modPath>mmmmmmmmm</modPath>
                <modInputTemplate>mmmmmmmm</modInputTemplate>
                <modSchematic>mmmmmm</modSchematic>
            </module>
        </computation>      
    </program>
    <program name="Rahul">
    .......
    .......
    .......
    </program>
    <program name="Ramesh">
    .......
    .......
    .......
    </program>
</root>
```

I have JS to display the Child nodes ,But its not based on the attribute value

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Read XML in Microsoft Browsers</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    function loadxml()
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = readXML;
        xmlDoc.load("writers.xml");
    }


    function readXML()
    {
        if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4){
            myFunction(xmlDoc);
        }
        function myFunction(xml) {
            var x, i, txt;
            txt = "";

            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("module");//Here "module" should be replaced by attribute value which user gives as i/p

            for( i = 0; i < x[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
                txt += x[0].childNodes[i].nodeName + ": " + x[0].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadxml()">
    <p id="demo">Write output of loadxml()</p>
    <p id="test">Test me!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: You don't specify what XML parser you are using, but if it supports it, XPath would be the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I have made changes to my HTML File please check

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to check for the desired attribute.

Your code gives back an array of modules:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("module");
```

The last thing for you to do is to go through the nodes and select only those with the desired attribute with:

```
// x is the array of modules, i stands for the array iteration    
x[i].getAttribute(name);
```

Now you can combine your desired input with the search algorithm.
Since you got Childnodes with Children it could get a little slow. You will always go through:

```
Parent -> Child.getAttribute -> new array -> Child.getAttribute.
```

The last thing for you to do is to check for the input with a normal if statement, it depends on how complicated your input is.

If anything is unclear, feel free to ask.

Regards, Megajin

Comment: I tried but din not get ,Can you please edit & show me for one i/p .Rest I will do

Comment: does i/p mean input? If yes you can just go for "document.getElementById('yourInputField').value" after you got the value you can store it in a variable and go on with your function.

Comment: Hi,i/p means Input..I don't have any ID here

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to locate part of XML document using complex filter. Example below shows XPath expression that will return all children elements of `module`, where `type` and `name` attributes of itself as well as the ancestors, match certain value :

```
var result = "";

var name = "Ram";
var type1 = "student";
var type2 = "a2";
var query = "/root/program[@name='" + name + "']/computation[@type='" + type1 + "']/module[@type='" + type2 + "']/*";

var nodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes(query);
for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    result += node.nodeName + ": " + node.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

Tested on IE11 and it shows the expected output after clicking on *"Allow blocked content"* prompt :

[image]

Output :

[image]

Comment: I am getting Blank ,Should i include any library ??

Comment: Worked without any library here in my windows 10's IE. Look at your IE console for errors, and learn to debug your javascript

Comment: its showing ActiveXObject is not defined 
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

Comment: Make sure you tested this in IE, and if you already did that, what is you IE version?

Comment: I have tested this on IE 10 ,

Comment: @Ram then I have no idea know why. The code indeed throwing exception when run on non-IE browser (tested in Firefox with exception *"ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined"*), but worked fine when tested in IE11 after I clicked `Enabled` on the ActiveX warning