# show xml tag content within html doc

Tags: html, xml

Im looking for a way to render or show my xml tag content within a html document, for example.

**something.xml**

```
<fudge>Green</fudge>
```

**test.html**

```
 <div id="fudge">
</div>
```

within the html div i would like Green to be printed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do this your HTML file should contain some JavaScript code, so you will want to learn how to parse XML in Javascript.

Here is a good StackOverflow question on this topic: [XML parsing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Ok thanks, i knew it was possible, just did not know how. ill look into it

Comment: **This should have been a vote to close as a duplicate, not an answer.  Recommend deletion.**