# extract XML values using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml

I have the below XML and 
i am trying to extract the data from it using java-script , any ideas on converting this using java script ?
The values from this XML needs to be exacted.

My question is different to the ones stated previously :

This XML has multiple child elements and these child elements can grown to 'n' number.

additional to this the values have to be stored in an array format .

```html
<MergeFields>
  <MergeItem>
    <Key>TotalPaymentAmountGST </Key>
    <Value>123.56</Value>
  </MergeItem>
  <MergeItem>
    <Key>TotalRefundAmountGST </Key>
    <Value>123.56 </Value>
  </MergeItem>
  <MergeItem>
    <Key>TotalPaymentAmount </Key>
    <Value>123.56 </Value>
  </MergeItem>
  <MergeItem>
    <Key>TotalRefundAmount </Key>
    <Value>123.56 </Value>
  </MergeItem>
  <MergeItem>
    <Key>StatementType </Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </MergeItem>

  <MergeItem>
    <Key>Transactions</Key>
    <Children>
      <MergeItem>
        <Key> 0 </Key>
        <Children>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key> PaymentDate </Key>
            <Value> 2017-07-31T03:41:02.537Z </Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key> DatePaidTo </Key>
            <Value> 2017-07-31T03:41:02.537Z </Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key> PaymentAmount </Key>
            <Value> 123.56 </Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>IsGSTAmount </Key>
            <Value>true</Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>RefundAmount</Key>
            <Value>123.56</Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>DishonouredAmount</Key>
            <Value>123.56</Value>
          </MergeItem>
        </Children>
      </MergeItem>
      <MergeItem>
        <Key> 1 </Key>
        <Children>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>PaymentDate </Key>
            <Value>2017-07-31T03:41:02.537Z</Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>DatePaidTo </Key>
            <Value>2017-07-31T03:41:02.537Z</Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>PaymentAmount </Key>
            <Value>123.56</Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>IsGSTAmount</Key>
            <Value> true</Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key> RefundAmount </Key>
            <Value> 123.56</Value>
          </MergeItem>
          <MergeItem>
            <Key>DishonouredAmount </Key>
            <Value> 123.56 </Value>
          </MergeItem>
        </Children>
      </MergeItem>
    </Children>
  </MergeItem>
</MergeFields>
```

Comment: There's an npm script i used recently to do just this on my node js server, would that answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @shard , I am looking to use javascript only ..

Comment: @Shiv npm is a package manager for javascript

Comment: @shard , please send it through ..

Answer (score 0):

[XML2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) npm package should be able to help, also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)